# metric space is open and closed.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

A open ball is a open set in metric.

I know the complement of an open set is a closed set and union of an open set is open set.

$d(y, 1) = 1, d(y, 2) = 1, d(y, 3) = 1, d(y, 4) = 1$ which is balls, $B(1,1), B(2,1), B(3,1), B(4,1)$ respectively.

By the definition, $B(x, r) =\{y \in X : d(x, y) < r\}$.

In this case, radius is 1 but they are equal to 1. If we take a radius 1/2 then it fails.

How are they open?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The closed ball of center $a$ with radius $p^{-n}$ is the open ball with center $a$ and $p^{-n+1}$. You can write an analogue statement to show that open balls are closed. The key here is that the image of $\mathbf{Q}$ by the absolute value, $p^{\mathbf{Z}}$, is a discrete subset in $\mathbf{R}$.